# Hybris product cockpit Compare mode MyTypedObject ClassCastException

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, cockpit

Hybris: product cockpit throws ClassCastException in compare mode for collections. In normal mode it works fine.

**How to explicitly cast MyTypedObject to collection?**

My code snippet:

```
Collection<CategoryModel> pCategories = ProductModel.getSupercategories();
  for (CategoryModel parentCategory : pCategories) { //ClassCastExceptionthrown
            //do something
  } }
```

**Stacktrace**:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 | java.lang.ClassCastException: de.hybris.platform.cockpit.services.meta.impl.ExtensibleTypeService$MyTypedObject cannot be cast to de.hybris.platform.category.model.CategoryModel
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at com.org.comm.hybris.core.servicelayer.attributehandlers.DynamicTSCategoryHandler.get(DynamicTSCategoryHandler.java:42)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at com.org.comm.hybris.core.servicelayer.attributehandlers.DynamicTSCategoryHandler.get(DynamicTSCategoryHandler.java:1)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.attribute.impl.DefaultDynamicAttributesProvider.get(DefaultDynamicAttributesProvider.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.getDynamicValue(ItemModelContextImpl.java:281)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at com.org.comm.hybris.core.model.ProductModel.getMyTSSuperCategory(ProductModel.java:1669)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:196)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/05/10 09:28:19.464 |     at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:181)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the HMC from the specific **product** which exactlly **supercategories** it has. As far as I know the **supercategories** dont have to be always from the type **CategoryModel**. It looks like you have extended your **CategoryModel** with **MyTypedObject**.

Than you have to do a check here before. Something like:

```
if (parentCategory instanceof ...)
```